# Confluent Schema Registry dies unexpectedly

Tags: apache-kafka, confluent-schema-registry

Schema registry is not starting immediately after the restart (controlled shutdown) of my confluent kafka (v3.3.0) cluster which is running on VM - SSL enabled. But if I try to restart after sometime (at least 2 hours after the kafka cluster restart) schema registry is starting fine. Error in logs: Unable to subscribe to the Kafka topic _schemas backing this data store. Topic may not exist.

I suspected cluster is not synced completely but I described the topic, its giving me expected result. please find below

`./bin/kafka-topics --describe --zookeeper localhost:2181 --topic _schemas
Topic:_schemas  PartitionCount:1        ReplicationFactor:3     Configs:cleanup.policy=compact
        Topic: _schemas Partition: 0    Leader: 2       Replicas: 2,3,1 Isr: 3,2,1`

Also, I checked the cluster status - all the 3 nodes in the cluster are in  sync. please find below

```
./bin/zookeeper-shell localhost:2181 <<< "ls /brokers/ids"
Connecting to localhost:2181
Welcome to ZooKeeper!
JLine support is disabled

WATCHER::

WatchedEvent state:SyncConnected type:None path:null
[1, 2, 3]
```

> [2019-07-08 09:07:14,132] DEBUG Partition map for /brokers/topics/_schemas is Map(0 -> List(2, 3, 1)) (kafka.utils.ZkUtils)
>   [2019-07-08 09:07:25,292] ERROR Server died unexpectedly:  (io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.rest.SchemaRegistryMain)
>   java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unable to subscribe to the Kafka topic _schemas backing this data store. Topic may not exist.
>           at io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.storage.KafkaStoreReaderThread.(KafkaStoreReaderThread.java:130)
>           at io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.storage.KafkaStore.init(KafkaStore.java:172)
>           at io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.storage.KafkaSchemaRegistry.init(KafkaSchemaRegistry.java:212)
>           at io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.rest.SchemaRegistryRestApplication.setupResources(SchemaRegistryRestApplication.java:56)
>           at io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.rest.SchemaRegistryRestApplication.setupResources(SchemaRegistryRestApplication.java:38)
>           at io.confluent.rest.Application.createServer(Application.java:157)

My schema-registry.properties:

```
listeners=https://XXXXXXXXXXXX:8081
kafkastore.connection.url=XXXX:2181,YYYY:2181,ZZZZ:2181
kafkastore.topic=_schemas
debug=true
kafkastore.timeout.ms=180000

kafkastore.ssl.key.password=changeit
kafkastore.ssl.keystore.location=/apps/KEYSTORE.jks
kafkastore.ssl.keystore.password=XXXX
kafkastore.ssl.truststore.location=/apps/TrustStore.jks
kafkastore.ssl.truststore.password=XXX
kafkastore.security.protocol=SSL
kafkastore.ssl.endpoint.identification.algorithm=HTTPS

ssl.keystore.location=/apps/KEYSTORE.jks
ssl.keystore.password=XXXXX
ssl.key.password=XXXXX
ssl.truststore.location=/apps/rustStore.jks
ssl.truststore.password=XXXXX
ssl.endpoint.identification.algorithm=HTTPS
zookeeper.set.acl=false
```

My server.properties

```
ssl.client.auth=required
ssl.keystore.location=/apps/KEYSTORE.jks
ssl.keystore.password=XXXXX
ssl.key.password=XXXXX
ssl.truststore.location=/apps/TrustStore.jks
ssl.truststore.password=XXXXX
security.inter.broker.protocol=SSL
ssl.keystore.type=JKS
ssl.truststore.type=JKS
ssl.enabled.protocols=TLSv1.2,TLSv1.1,TLSv1
ssl.endpoint.identification.algorithm=HTTPS
zookeeper.set.acl=false
```

Comment: `state:SyncConnected` doesn't mean the brokers are in-sync... `Replicas: 2,3,1 Isr: 3,2,1` does... In any case, please show your registry properties and ensure that your ssl settings are correct so that it can create/describe the schema topic

Comment: @cricket_007 - I have added configuration. Please check.

Comment: @cricket_007 Sorry, It was typo for this post (edited now) . In my actual configuration, it is correct.